# Custom Social share button added is not shown for configurable products

Tags: magento2.2, category-products, social-buttons

I am trying to add social share buttons for the magento2 store products. Its working fine for Simple products. But for the configurable products, a button is not shown.

Can anyone help me solving this?

Comment: show your code for simple product which you have used

Comment: Add the code snippet to your question.

Comment: Post question with your code.

Comment: try this extension https://github.com/mageprashant/magento2-sharebuttons-module